# iOS 8 - Accessing camera from HTML input breaks layout when run from homescreen as webapp

Tags: html, ios8, iphone-standalone-web-app

When running a web app from the home screen on iOS 8, the page layout breaks (scales and resizes everything incorrectly) after the camera is accessed from a file upload HTML element.

I have the following `<meta>` tags in my document head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

The file upload element is a simple input:

```
<input type="file">Input</input>
```

The file upload actually works, but the page layout is broken once the camera app is closed. Note that the camera app takes up the full screen when it is accessed by the browser this way.

Comment: Perhaps you should file this as a bug against Apple. Remember to post it and updates to it on [openradar](http://openradar.me/) so other interested people (like me) can follow along ;-).

Comment: Opened an issue on apple bug reporter. Problem ID: 19599472